# Overwrite WSDL magento API v2

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v2, wsdl

I've got a question. I am changing the following function from the Magento API V2: `catalogProductAttributeSetAttributeAdd()`.

In the WSDL I defined I want the ID back, and not a boolean.

My problem is: I have to change core templates: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml` like this:

`<!-- <message name="catalogProductAttributeSetAttributeAddResponse">
    <part name="isAdded" type="xsd:boolean" />
</message> -->`

but I don't want to do that.

How can I overwrite this line in the wsdl.xml? My new WSDL looks like:

```
<message name="catalogProductAttributeSetAttributeAddResponse">
    <part name="attributeId" type="xsd:int" />
</message>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well remember all wsdl files are merged into one big, so you can create a wdsl.xml in your custom module and override the needed node(s) keeping the same name(s).
Tell me if it works :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It will merge the XMLs together. But when I use the same name, it just turns up twice in the wsdl.xml...

Comment: Ah ok I think it's because the "attributeId" parameter doesn't have the same name, so the merge doesn't replace the "isAdded" parameter but it actually add it. If you want the method 'catalogProductAttributeSetAttributeAdd' to return only the attributeId, you'll have to create a whole new API method... A wiki is avaible here : https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/How+to+Override+an+Existing+API+Class+with+Additional+Functionality.